# RASM2 can't re-assemble its own disassembly output for ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm, disassembly, thumb

In case I run the code below on Linux:

```
rasm2 -a arm -b 16 -d "28 46 0d f2 74 4d f0 bd"
```

Result is:

```
mov r0, r5
addw sp, sp, 0x474
pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
```

---

But now the question is, if I try to re-assemble the disassembly back into hexadecimal machine code again, it doesn't work:

```
rasm2 -a arm -b 16 "mov r0, r5;addw sp, sp, 0x474;pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc};"
```

```
Cannot assemble 'addw sp, sp, 0x474' at line 8
invalid
```

This is what happened.

So how can I assemble my assembly code to a hexadecimal in an accurate way, using rasm2 or else,
and what is the reason of that error?

Comment: Do you need an argument to tell it what encoding to ouput, eg: arm, thumb, thumb2 etc?  That is a valid instruction in ARMv7M at least.

Comment: @TomV My target machine is Cortex m4(which is ARMv7M), should be alright according to your comment...

Comment: Don't tell me, use the `-a arm -b 16 -c cortex` arguments to tell the assembler!

Comment: Tried, but still doesn't help :(

Comment: It assembles just fine with GAS using `.cpu cortex-m4` and `.syntax unified`.  Maybe report a bug in rasm2.

Comment: did you try:  addw sp, sp, #0x474  not sure why you would assume that the disassembly can be re-assembled, that is not a common expectation, nor the goal of a disassembler...perhaps in this case it is an advertised feature.

Comment: @old_timer Actually, my attempt is to re-assemble modified code(just erased last branch command). I need new hex with no branch so I'm generating modified code which does not contain those.

Comment: Typically, the syntax is `add.w sp,sp,#0x474`.  Try changing to use 'add.w'.  It would be a bug in the way it output 'wide' forms of the instruction (if the intent is bi-directional; but this is probably a desirable property).  It is four bytes.  0d f2 74 4d.  The same can be done with `printf` and `objdump`.